# How to use an attribute of a class to create a fixed size array?

Tags: c++, arrays, class

I have a class that contains two attributes: an int and a fixed size array. How can I make it so that I can use the int to fix the size of my array?

I tried this way but I can't seem to make it work:

```
#include "tile.h"

class board {
private:
    const static int m_RADIUS;
    static tile[2 * m_RADIUS - 1][2 * m_RADIUS - 1];
};
```

Comment: How are you going to know what the value of `m_RADIUS` should be?

Comment: You could use templates. I don't know of any other way (besides using dynamic memory), but that doesn't seem to be what you're after

Answer (score 4):

Sizes of all array variables must be compile time constant. A static const variable is a compile time constant expression only after it has been defined using a compile time constant initialiser.

You cannot give a non-inline static member variable an initialiser within the class definition, but you can give an initialiser if you use an inline variable instead. You also must give a name for the member array. Example:

```
inline const static int m_RADIUS = 42;
static tile array[2 * m_RADIUS - 1][2 * m_RADIUS - 1];
```

Comment: Also, you could replace `const` by `constexpr` to force the member to be a compile time constant.